# Powershell Invoke-Command -ErrorVariable output is incomplete

Tags: powershell, error-handling, invoke-command

So I have been trying to get a complete error message and stack trace from Invoke-Command errors and have not had any luck.

I ran this code:

```
Invoke-command -COMPUTER "TESTCOMPUTER" -ScriptBlock {

    klist purge -li 0x3e7

    Return Get-Service

} -ErrorVariable errmsg

Write-Host "`r`nError: $errmsg"
```

And this is the output I received in the console:

[TESTCOMPUTER] Connecting to remote server TESTCOMPUTER failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. 
Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the 
WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to 
remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (TESTCOMPUTER) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

Error: [TESTCOMPUTER] Connecting to remote server TESTCOMPUTER failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. 
Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinR
M service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remot
e computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

As you can see, the second portion is a copy of the error missing the stack trace. How can I get that entire error into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ErrorVariable is a `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`.
If you do a `Get-Member` on this variable, you can see it has these methods and properties:

```
Name                  MemberType     Definition
----                  ----------     ----------
Equals                Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode           Method         int GetHashCode()
GetObjectData         Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISeri...
GetType               Method         type GetType()
ToString              Method         string ToString()
writeErrorStream      NoteProperty   bool writeErrorStream=True
CategoryInfo          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategoryInfo CategoryInfo {get;}
ErrorDetails          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorDetails ErrorDetails {get;set;}
Exception             Property       System.Exception Exception {get;}
FullyQualifiedErrorId Property       string FullyQualifiedErrorId {get;}
InvocationInfo        Property       System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo InvocationInfo {get;}
PipelineIterationInfo Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[int] PipelineIterationInfo {get;}
ScriptStackTrace      Property       string ScriptStackTrace {get;}
TargetObject          Property       System.Object TargetObject {get;}
PSMessageDetails      ScriptProperty System.Object PSMessageDetails {get=& { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Exception.InnerException.PSMessageDetails };}
```

If you leave out the `Write-Host` and just end your code with

```
$errmsg
```

It will return the whole error (in error color i.e. Red)

You can construct the complete error message by combining the different properties of the `$errmsg` object like this:

```
$err = "`r`nError: {0}`r`n    + CategoryInfo          : {1}`r`n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {2}" -f $errmsg.ErrorDetails, $errmsg.CategoryInfo, $errmsg.FullyQualifiedErrorId
Write-Host $err
```

Or using a Here-String for better readability:

```
$err = @"
Error: $($errmsg.ErrorDetails)
    + CategoryInfo          : $($errmsg.CategoryInfo)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : $($errmsg.FullyQualifiedErrorId)
"@ 
Write-Host $err
```

There may even be more properties of interest to add to it, but that is up to you.